# how to create user role wise access control in user and role table joining in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, access-control, cakephp-3.x, rbac

**user table**

[image]

**role table**

[image]

I just want to allow access control to role table set like: `ctrl_view = 1` means this role can view any controller view.

How can I set different action in different role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions), user_role_id should be named "role_id", role_id only "id" and user_name should be "username" or inside your [Auth configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) change the default fields name use for your connection form.

```
public function initialize() 
    {
//...
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
              'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'welcome',
                'prefix' => 'admin' 
              ],
              'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
                'prefix' => false
              ],
              'authError' => 'Unauthorized access...',
              'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                  'fields' => ['username' => 'user_name', 'password' => 'password']
                ]
              ],
              'authorize' => 'Controller',
              'unauthorizedRedirect' => [
                  'controller' => 'Pages',
                  'action' => 'unauthorized'
                ],
            ]);
// ...
}
```

and inside your Appcontroller make somtehing like this

```
 public function isAuthorized($user)
      {

          if(!is_null($this->Auth->user())): // if user is logged

            $action = $this->request->getParam('action'); // get name action

            $this->loadModel('Roles'); // load your model Roles
            $query = $this->Authorizations->find() // find inside Roles
            ->where([
            'Roles.role_id IN' => $user['user_role_id'], // where role_id is like user_role_id of current user
            'Roles.ctl_'.$action => 1 // and where ctl_[action] is set to 1
            ])->toArray();

            if (!empty($query)): // if we find an occurence, we allow the action
              return true;
            else: // else we don't authorize
              return false,
            endif;

            /* previous lines can be change with this  ----> return (!empty($query)); */
          else: // if user is not connected we don't allow action
            return false
          endif;
    }
```

and to finish, i think it's better to use "prefix", with prefix u can simplify your authorisation process (will no prefix i allow, with prefix i check my role table), for this you have to simply add these line in the beginin of your isAuthorized function:

```
if (!$this->request->getParam('prefix')) {
    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps